# Что делать, если для нескольких страниц применяется один стиль, но на одной из них нужно сместить елемент, оставив прежние места на других?

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть несколько страниц, для которых активен css файл с стилями. Есть один элемент, который на другой странице должен быть расположен в другом месте.

Как изменить стиль конкретно для одного элемента, оставив прежние стили для других с таким же id?

Comment: 1. Дайте класс этому элементу и задайте стиль для этого класса

Comment: 2. Либо меняете стили сразу в head > style страницы.

Comment: 3. Либо задайте стиль прямо этому элементу с помощью `style` аттрибута

Comment: 4. Либо прикрепите странице отдельный лист стилей

Comment: 4 метода достаточно? 

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в строку Ваше оформление с нужными параметрами и обязательно укажите что оно важнее (`!important`), чем библиотечный стиль из файла стилей. Например так:

```
<div id="Ваш идентификатор" style="margin-left: color: red; 50px!important;">Привет, как дела?!</div>
```

Comment: Inline-стиль и без ``!important`` имеет больший приоритет (специфичность), чем стиль из файла, кроме случая, когда стиль в файле с ``!important``, чего, по идее, следует избегать.